# jQuery ui drag and drop works incorrectly in Chrome when helper is set to clone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

my application works fine in FF and IE but it works in an unexpected way in Chrome.
I'm using jquery to implement a drag and drop behaviour of chess pieces on a chess board.
I found out that using helper: "clone" option triggers the wrong behaviour in Chrome.
The correct behaviour is: the piece must drop on the square it overlaps at least 50% (the default intersect tolerance).
The Chrome behaviour is: the piece drops on the upper square it touches.

```
$(".piece-draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    // with "helper" option set to "clone" the drop is incorrect: moving only the 
    // top of the king piece to g5 
    // it happens the king is misplaced to g6 (onDrop is called from g6).
    // This behaviour affects only Chrome while FF works as expected.
    // without using the helper, all browsers works fine    
    helper: "clone",
    containment: ".board",
    start: onDragStart,
    stop: onDragStop
});

$(".square20").droppable({
    drop: onDrop
});

function onDragStart(event, ui) {
    $("#text").append("<p>start</p>");
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.35");
    $(ui.helper).css("opacity", "1");
}

function onDragStop(event, ui) {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $("#text").append("<p>stop</p>");
}

function onDrop(event, ui) {
    //ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
    //$(this).droppable('disable');
    ui.draggable.position({
        of: $(this),
        my: 'center',
        at: 'center'
    });


    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    $("#text").append("<p>" + "drop " + $(this).attr("id") + "</p>");
}


$(".piece-draggable").draggable('enable');

$(".square20").droppable('enable');​
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxqua72/nnQLZ/7/) example. You can try moving the black king to g5, just touching the g6 square: the king will be placed on g6!

How can I fix this nasty problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the behaviour by adding the following CSS snippet:

```
img.piece-draggable {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

By observing the incorrect behaviour, it seemed to me that the cloned image was acting as if it had zero width and zero height, i.e., the upper-left corner of the absolute positioned image was dictating the DROP destination, ignoring the image dimensions.

So, my first try was to "provide" this "missing" width/height... and it worked.

Now, with the help of this useful "discovery" you can elaborate a more suitable solution, based on your needs and requirements...

Comment: Thanks! It works setting the missing width/height. I was not able to find anywhere else any information about this issue even if it seems to me it is a quite nasty bug.